# Flume 1.6.0 spooling directory source with timestamp on header

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to create a new flume agent like `source spooldir` and puts them in HDFS. This is my config file:

```
agent.sources = file
agent.channels = channel
agent.sinks = hdfsSink

# SOURCES CONFIGURATION
agent.sources.file.type = spooldir
agent.sources.file.channels = channel
agent.sources.file.spoolDir = /path/to/json_files

# SINKS CONFIGURATION
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.path = /HADOOP/PATH/%Y/%m/%d/%H/

agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.filePrefix = common
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.fileSuffix = .json
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollSize = 5242880
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 2
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.callTimeout = 100000
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.channel = channel

# CHANNELS CONFIGURATION
agent.channels.channel.type = memory
agent.channels.channel.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.channel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

I'm getting an error that describes **`Expected timestamp in the Flume event headers, but it was null`**. The files that I'm reading contains JSON structure, which has a field named `timestamp`.

Is there a way to add this timestamp in the header?

Comment: let me try and definitely return with results, but it will take a span of hours, ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as explained in this post:
http://shzhangji.com/blog/2017/08/05/how-to-extract-event-time-in-apache-flume/

the changes needed is to include an interceptor and serializer to it:

```
# SOURCES CONFIGURATION
agent.sources.file.type = spooldir
agent.sources.file.channels = channel
agent.sources.file.spoolDir = /path/to/json_files
agent.sources.file.interceptors = i1
agent.sources.file.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor
agent.sources.file.interceptors.i1.regex = <regex_for_timestamp>
agent.sources.file.interceptors.i1.serializers = s1
agent.sources.file.interceptors.i1.serializers.s1.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.RegexExtractorInterceptorMillisSerializer
agent.sources.file.interceptors.i1.serializers.s1.name = timestamp
agent.sources.file.interceptors.i1.serializers.s1.pattern = <pattern_that_matches_your_regex>
```

thanks for pointing out that besides the link i needed to include a proper snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my earlier comment, now I am sharing the entire steps which I followed and performed for `spooling header enable json file`, putting it to `hadoop hdfs` cluster using `flume`, creating a external file over `json` file and later performed `DML query` over it -

**Created `flume-spool.conf`**

```
//Flume Configuration Starts
erum.sources =source-1
erum.channels =file-channel-1
erum.sinks =hdfs-sink-1

erum.sources.source-1.channels =file-channel-1
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.channel =file-channel-1

//Define a file channel called fileChannel on erum
erum.channels.file-channel-1.type =file 

erum.channels.file-channel-1.capacity =2000000
erum.channels.file-channel-1.transactionCapacity =100000

//Define a source for erum
erum.sources.source-1.type =spooldir
erum.sources.source-1.bind =localhost
erum.sources.source-1.port =44444
erum.sources.source-1.inputCharset =UTF-8
erum.sources.source-1.bufferMaxLineLength =100

//Spooldir in my case is /home/arif/practice/flume_sink
erum.sources.source-1.spoolDir =/home/arif/practice/flume_sink/
erum.sources.source-1.fileHeader =true
erum.sources.source-1.fileHeaderKey=file
erum.sources.source-1.fileSuffix =.COMPLETED

//Sink is flume_import under hdfs
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.pathManager =DEFAULT
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.type =hdfs

erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.filePrefix =common
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.fileSuffix =.json
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.writeFormat =Text
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.fileType =DataStream
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.path =hdfs://localhost:9000/user/arif/flume_sink/products/

erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.batchSize =1000
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollSize =2684354560
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollInterval =5
erum.sinks.hdfs-sink-1.hdfs.rollCount =5000
```

**Now we are running the flume-spool using agent - `erum`**

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n erum -c conf -f conf/flume-spool.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

**Copied the `products.json` file inside the `erum.sources.source-1.spoolDir` `flume` configured specified directory.**

**Contents inside the `products.json` file is as follows as it were -**

```
{"productid":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001","product_name":"sildenafilcitrate","mfgdate":"20160719031109","supplier":"WisozkInc","quantity":261,"unit_cost":"$10.47"}
{"productid":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002","product_name":"MountainJuniperusashei","mfgdate":"20161003021009","supplier":"Keebler-Hilpert","quantity":292,"unit_cost":"$8.74"}
{"productid":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003","product_name":"DextromathorphanHBr","mfgdate":"20161101041113","supplier":"Schmitt-Weissnat","quantity":211,"unit_cost":"$20.53"}
{"productid":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000004","product_name":"MeophanHBr","mfgdate":"20161101061113","supplier":"Schmitt-Weissnat","quantity":198,"unit_cost":"$18.73"}
```

**Download the hive-serdes-sources-1.0.6.jar from below url-**

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsjgk2zaqz8uli9/hive-serdes-sources-1.0.6.jar?dl=0
```

**After spooling the json file to hdfs cluster using flume-spool, we will start the hive server, login to hive shell and then do the following-**

```
hive> add jar /home/arif/applications/hadoop/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-serdes-sources-1.0.6.jar;
hive> create external table products (productid string, product_name string, mfgdate string, supplier string, quantity int, unit_cost string) 
    > row format serde 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' location '/user/arif/flume_sink/products/';
OK
Time taken: 0.211 seconds
hive> select * from products;
OK
5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001    sildenafilcitrate   20160719031109  WisozkInc   261 $10.47
5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002    MountainJuniperusashei  20161003021009  Keebler-Hilpert 292 $8.74
5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003    DextromathorphanHBr 20161101041113  Schmitt-Weissnat    211 $20.53
5968dd23fc13ae04d9000004    MeophanHBr  20161101061113  Schmitt-Weissnat    198 $18.73
Time taken: 0.291 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

and I have completed these entire steps without any single error, hope this will help you, thanks.

Comment: hi arifmustafa, thanks for the reply, the problem with your answer is that the hadoop directory is static and doesn't use the timestamp in the header, that's why is not an appropriate solution for my problem